# rbenv command line gems setup with system install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, chef-infra, rbenv

I am using the chef `rbenv` recipe (https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rbenv), doing a system wide install (goes into /usr/local/rbenv) with the rails lastmile cookbook (https://github.com/DanThiffault/rails-lastmile). The server works fine, I can install gems, but command line gems don't seem to work (`valkyrie`, `mysql2psql`).

Do I need to do additional work to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to rbenv from rvm where it just seemed to work.  It looks like in rbenv you have to run :

```
bundle exec gemxx
```

Or generate binstubs:

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Understanding-binstubs

Answer (score 1):

You have to run [`rbenv rehash`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash) everytime you install a gem with a command line script when using rbenv.

If you installed the gems in a bundle and are running the command from within the directory where the `Gemfile` is located, @riley's suggestion might be enough. Otherwise, `rehash` is the command that will make the executables available on the path.